# ruby spidr can't spider "gb2312" coding html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler, gb2312

Why ruby spidr can't spider "gb2312" coding html page? Can it only spider "utf-8" coding page?
This is my code:

```
Spidr.site('http://www.lookmw.cn/') do |spider|
  spider.every_page do |page|
    puts "[-] #{page.url}"

  end
end
```

It answers: "encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xAB 0x69 0xA3 0xAC"
What can i do ?